# Would anyone be interested in a group watching event?

Tags: discussion, chat-event

The was proposed with Star Trek TOS but I don't think it came into fruition. But I'd like to propose a monthly/bimonthly event were people can sign up for a chat event and we all watch the same movie or TV show together and chat about it live in chat. The chat conversation can then be posted (edited down to only on topic conversations) to the blog for everyone to enjoy.

There was also talk, if this becomes successful, that we can transcribe the chat logs into subtitle tracks and post a downloadable for people to use when they want to watch the movie at a later date and see what their fellow SciFi-ers had to say in real time to the movie.

What say you? Anyone interested?

If you are, post a suggested first movie to watch and a time we can get together in chat. Once we come to a concensus, I can (or those with the power of Greyskull) can schedule the event in the chat and those wishing to participate would then sign up for the event. Email reminders are sent out automatically if it's done that way.

**Edit:**

We've decided on Star Trek TOS.  See the scheduling discussion [over here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/sci-fi-fantasy-group-watching-chat-event-schedule-ideas).

Comment: Related: [book club](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-club) on [literature.se]; [Movie night idea](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/189/movie-night-idea) on [movies.se]

Comment: @gilles true, but ours will be awesomer

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Make it so.

Comment: I was thinking a book club sort of thing might work better than a simultaneous viewing.  Our population is pretty global, so it's hard to schedule an event that we can all attend.  If instead we do a 'watch 3 episodes this week, then chat about it on Saturday' sort of thing, we can get more attendance.  Either way, I'm in.

Comment: I just wanted the hilarity of watching it all at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

I'll suggest Star Trek The Original Series.  It's been a while since I last saw it, and I bet most people haven't seen it themselves.

Comment: I think we should pick one of the worstST:TOS episodes (Either _Spock's Brain_ or _And the Children Shall Lead_) and do it MST3K style.

Comment: I think this whole thing should be MST3K style lol

Comment: Everything about the original series, utterly glorious as it is, is totally ripe material for mocking.  All the 60s norms that bleed through to the writing are awesome.  Not to mention the lute playing...

Comment: As I've never seen TOS, I'm sure I can have some laughs with everyone else. When do you guys wanna do this? I know that TOS is on Netflix for the next couple years, so it will be easy enough for some to watch them at the same time.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I think you should create a separate meta question for scheduling.

Comment: This sounds pretty good, and it is on Netflix instant. That makes it easy.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion is Firefly, followed by Serenity.  I'm pretty sure all sci-fi fans own a copy of this by now.

Answer (score 2):

Back to the Future would be another great title to watch.

Answer (score 0):

Wing Commander the cartoon TV series. Lesser known, but great quality sci-fi. (Way better than the terrible Wing Commander movie.) The fact that it is not as popular means that we'll have more fresh eyes watching it for the first time. Won't that make the conversation more interesting?